# bash extglob range-or-value matching same file name twice

Tags: bash, glob, extglob

Given these files:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file21  file3  fileFoo
```

I expected this globbing pattern (bash with extglob enabled):

```
$ ls file?({1..2}|Foo)
```

to output:

```
file1  file2  fileFoo
```

but instead I got this with `fileFoo` listed twice:

```
$ ls file?({1..2}|Foo)
file1  file2  fileFoo  fileFoo
```

Neither side of the "or" produces unexpected results:

```
$ ls file?({1..2})
file1  file2

$ ls file?(Foo)
fileFoo
```

so why is `fileFoo` printed twice when I "or" the expressions and what would be the correct globbing pattern to match a range (e.g. 1-2 above but could be 17-593 or any other range) or some other unrelated string (e.g. Foo above)?

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
```

Comment: Why use a range if it's just 2 consecutive numbers?

Comment: Like I say in the question, that's just a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expansion is performed before globbing:

```
file?({1..2}|Foo)
```

becomes

```
file?(1|Foo) file?(2|Foo)
```

and then both arguments are globbed.

Using only expansion as follows works as expected, but will trip up `nullglob` and the like:

```
file{{1..2},Foo}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's being interpreted as:

```
ls file?(1|Foo) file?(2|Foo)
```

The range is being expanded and then each value is combined with `|Foo`.

So when each pattern is expanded, you get both the file ending with a number and the file ending with `Foo`.

Try:

```
ls file{{1..2},Foo)
```

Comment: Yup that was it thanks, upvoting but will have to accept Ignacios almost identical answer as he beat you be a couple of mins.